# Error: Unable to connect to kuzzle server at 127.0.0.1:7512: Connection lost. (ws status=503)

Tags: kuzzle

i receive lot of :

```
[kuzzle networkError] :  Error: Unable to connect to kuzzle server at 127.0.0.1:7512: Connection lost. (ws status=503)
```

since i start using apikey from createApikey, may it be related to a bad usage of the token ?
seems to happen after every successful query

Comment: Hi, which api action are you using for this successful query ? Also, could you provide the kuzzle logs after the successfull query ?

Comment: Hi, it's ok now; the problem was due to misusage of the createapikey; i was still doing login after the apikey creation and setting.